# What are the equivalents of C#'s access modifiers in Java and Scala?

Tags: c#, java, scala, access-modifiers

Having previously worked in C#, I now spend a lot of time working in Scala and Java.  This can be confusing, because the three languages use similar names for their access modifiers but don't always mean the same thing.

What are the equivalents of C#'s access modifiers in Java and Scala?

Comment: I'm attempting to answer my own question, which is encouraged. ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question ) Any corrections and improvements are welcome. I searched for this but couldn't find the info summarized in one place, which I think is useful to have.

Comment: All of this information is already plenty well documented.  A simple google search for access modifiers in each relevant language results in plenty of good information for what they are and what they do.  The fact that you have answered the question yourself in no way lowers the standards for question quality; asking a question that demonstrates a clear lack of research effort is a low quality question, and any answers you may post to it don't change that.

Comment: @Servy I did in fact do research, and you're right that the information can be gleaned from combining several results, e.g.: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_access_modifiers.htm http://j2eethoughts.wordpress.com/2010/12/12/access-modifiers-scala-java/ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228632(v=vs.90).aspx  However I felt like having the information all summarized in one place was useful as a quick reference, and thus the sort of thing I would blog, if I had a blog.

Comment: The answer from meta.stackoverflow.com I linked above says "Before Stack Overflow I would write a blog post so I could google for it later. Jeff and Joel I think specifically said SO is a good place to replace these blog posts."  So that was what I tried to do.

Comment: And if you could do it in such a way that the post would be an acceptable SO question, that'd be great.  As it is, it is not, because it's just repeating information already widely accessible.

Comment: Accessible but scattered on a bunch of different pages.  And I would argue that most stackoverflow answers duplicate information already available elsewhere on the internet.  At any rate, I'm fine with letting the votes decide if it's useful or not.

Comment: The top search result for each relevant language provides all of the information needed for understanding the accessibility modifiers for that language.  There's no need to look at multiple pages.

Comment: @Servy Having actually gone through the exercise of trying to understand it based on the top search results, I can assure you that this was not the case.  For example, the top search result for "scala access modifiers", given here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_access_modifiers.htm was quite helpful, but all it says about `protected[X]` is that it means "protected up to X".  That did not make it clear to me that it was *both* accessible everywhere a protected member would be (even outside X), and accessible everywhere within X.

Comment: In other words, it's a lot like how C#'s protected internal means "all the accessibility of protected plus all the accessibility of internal."  I didn't understand that until I read this page: http://j2eethoughts.wordpress.com/2010/12/12/access-modifiers-scala-java/ which says: "Previously we said that scoped protected and private behave identically except under inheritance. The only difference is that [...] independently of the scope stated, a member defined with protected[something] is visible for any subclass, while when defined with private[something] is not."

Comment: As another example, the top result for "java access modifiers", here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html says "The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package."

Comment: This doesn't remotely make clear (to me) that while you can't call the protected member on an instance of the base class from within the derived class *if the derived class is in a different package than the base class*, you *can* do such if the derived class and the base class are in the same package.

Comment: What did make it clear was experimenting with it and then realizing it was like protected internal in C#, where within a derived class in the same assembly as the base class you can call a protected member on an instance of the base class, but not within a derived class within a different assembly than the base class.

Comment: So what you're saying is that the top search result defines the exact correct mechanisms for what should happen, but you didn't read it, assumed that it meant the same thing as in another language, were confused, and so you're repeating that exact same definition here.  Sorry, but I fail to see any value in that.

Comment: That's not *at all* what I just said.  I said the top link for Scala access modifiers (which I did read), gives a very terse description of the difference between `protected[X]` and `private[X]`.  It is not obvious that "protected up to X" means "available even outside of X where a protected member is available, as well as available everywhere within X, even outside the class hierarchy."  I had to read multiple pages to get to that info, and to clarify the difference in protected in Java, etc.

Comment: Seriously, what part of me saying "These are some of the specific pages I read, and the details I felt they didn't make clear" makes you conclude I read nothing?  If you really want to say "No question that can be answered by 3 Google searches should be posted on Stack Overflow, fine, I disagree but that's a valid opinion.  (I also disagree that this question can be answered by 3 google searches, but maybe your google-fu is stronger than mine.)   If you want to say I did no research, that is factually inaccurate.

Comment: You specifically quoted an article that made a specific point.  Then you rambled on for several paragraphs about how you didn't understand that it did that thing that you specifically quoted it as explaining and that it was confusing because some other language has different semantics.  Other than explaining why you were confused, all you ended up saying was the same information from the article you quoted as being "incomplete".  Either you didn't read it, or you're lacking in reading comprehension.  Either way, duplicating it isn't helping anyone.

Comment: As for it being appropriate to post questions that can be solved by simply throwing the question into Google, yes, it *is* site policy that those are bad questions.  Questions on SO are expected to have been researched; if you cannot so much as bother to throw your question into a search engine before asking it, then the question most certainly isn't ready to be asked on SO.  Creating *yet another* page with *the exact same information* isn't helping anyone, and it consumes the time of everyone looking through this page.

Comment: @Servy Do you think I'm lying when I say I Googled it?  My "rambling on" described what I read, and why I didn't have a full understanding from just the top result for each of "[C#/Java/Scala] access modifiers", and why I felt an explanation aimed more at people with a C# background would be useful.

Comment: @Servy I'm fine with the downvote if you don't personally find it useful relative to the Google results. I'm just a bit bothered that you seem to be rather angrily declaring I "cannot so much as bother to throw [my] question into a search engine" when that was simply not true.  I both read multiple search results and tested code, and I thought that posting my findings might spare someone else the trouble. (Obviously not thinking of experts with 80k stack overflow rep, here.)

Comment: At the end of the day, despite the fact that you were somewhat confused by some of the articles that you read, your actual posts contains no information not already there.  Someone who couldn't be bothered to throw this question into google to find those articles isn't going to find your article.  Someone who *is* going to do a web search for the information they're looking for *will* find the information that they're looking for.  Nobody ends up benefiting from you writing your answer.

Comment: @Servy Well, this page is now the top Google result for "Scala vs C# access modifiers" (maybe just because of recent activity, I don't know) and explains it in a way that makes sense to me, so maybe it'll save time for someone else coming from a similar background.  But like I said, I don't mind the downvote, I just objected to the "lack of research" accusation.  I guess you feel like it was a trivial amount of research, and only seemed substantial enough to warrant a question/answer because I was stupidly not understanding it right away.  Ah well, sorry to waste your time then.

Comment: It's not a matter of how much research you did, its a matter of what research the question *demonstrates*.  The question demonstrates no research whatsoever, on a topic with plenty of easily discoverable information.  If, on the other hand, the question was explaining what research was done, and in what ways you were confused as a result of what you found, *then* it could potentially be a good question.

Comment: @Servy OK, I see the distinction you're drawing.  The thing is, if I had stopped after I'd read the initial pages I read, I would have included lots of details of the form "This site says X, which I interpret to mean XYZ, but that can't be right because it disagrees with observed behavior W..."  But because I persisted until I was actually able to answer my question, it no longer seemed useful to include the things I initially found confusing or misunderstood.

Comment: If the answers to the points that you found confusing or hard to understand were *also* reasonably easy to find the answers to due to a reasonable amount of research/effort then apparently you don't have anything particularly helpful to share.  If you had information that you feel is hard to discover or find a solution for then asking a question about *that* would be well suited for the site.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here are the closest equivalents to C#'s access modifiers within Java and Scala.  **In the case of internal (accessible within the same assembly), there is no exact equivalent.**  In Java you can limit accessibility to the same package, but packages are more directly equivalent to C#'s namespaces than they are to assemblies.

("no modifier" in the following table is interpreted as applying to class members.  That is, in C# class members with no modifier are private.  This is not true of top-level types, which default to internal.)

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| C#                  | Java            | Scala                    | Meaning                                                                                                       |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| no modifier         | private (1)     | private                  | accessible only within the class where it is defined                                                          |
| private             |                 |                          |                                                                                                               |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| protected           |   --            | protected                | accessible within the class and within derived classes (2)                                                    |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| internal            | no modifier     | private[package_name]    | accessible within the same assembly (C#) or within the same package (Java / Scala) (3)                        |
| ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| protected internal  | protected       | protected[package_name]  | accessible within derived classes (2) and anywhere in the same assembly (C#) or package (Java / Scala) (3)    |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| public              | public          | no modifier              | accessible anywhere                                                                                           |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

(1) In Java, private members of an inner class are visible to the outer class, but that's not true in C# or Scala.  In Scala, you can say private[X] where X is the outer class to get the Java behavior.

(2) In C# and Scala, a protected member is visible within a class if it's a member of an instance of that class or a further derived class, but not if it's a member of an instance of a less-derived class.  (The same is true in Java, except where it's accessible due to being in the same package.)

Example (in C#):

```
class Base
{
    protected void Foo() {}

    void Test()
    {
        Foo(); // legal
        this.Foo(); // legal

        new Base().Foo(); // legal
        new Derived().Foo(); // legal
        new MoreDerived().Foo(); // legal
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    void Test1()
    {
        Foo(); // legal
        this.Foo(); // legal

        new Base().Foo(); // illegal !
        new Derived().Foo(); // legal
        new MoreDerived().Foo(); // legal
    }
}

class MoreDerived : Derived
{
    void Test2()
    {
        Foo(); // legal
        this.Foo(); // legal

        new Base().Foo(); // illegal !
        new Derived().Foo(); // illegal !
        new MoreDerived().Foo(); // legal
    }
}
```

(3) In Scala, you can get the Java behavior by specifying the inner-most package, but you can also specify any enclosing package.

Comment: Your first row in table for Scala, `no modifier`. Isn't Scala public by default (as you've shown below)? Unless I'm misreading your table.

Comment: In the first cell I listed no modifier under private to indicate they're the same in C#.  Maybe I can make that more clear?

Comment: So no modifier in C# means the equivalent of `private` in other languages?

Comment: no modifier in C# is the equivalent of `private` in other languages, *and* it's the equivalent of `private` in C#.  That is, `private` is the default.  However, that's only true for class members, I believe top level classes default to internal.  I should probably edit to include that info.

Comment: isn't C# assembly analogue to java's jar? thus your `internal` comparison isn't precise

Comment: @om-nom-nom That's true, and I noted it in the first paragraph.  That said, I think that the package-level visibility is the *closest* equivalent, in the sense that it lets you make the member visible to other classes outside of your inheritance hierarchy, while still not making it visible to everyone.  In particular, coming from a C# background, being able to say of Java's `protected` "Oh, it's kind of like `protected internal`" was helpful to me.

Comment: @om-nom-nom No, worries.  I just edited to bold that line, because I imagine a lot of people's eyes will be drawn first to the table, and I wouldn't want them to be misled.

Comment: In Scala, you have `sealed` templates (that's the generic term for "trait or class" that is used in the language specification), which can be extended within the same compilation unit (typically: the same file) but cannot be extended outside of it (i.e. are `final` from the outside). There is no equivalent in either C# (I think) or Java (I know), but it is tremendously useful in cases where you want an (abstract) template to have exactly a given set of subclasses. That's how you encode closed algebraic sum types for example.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thank you for the comment.  I believe you're right that there is no equivalent for Scala `sealed` in C#.  C# `sealed` is equivalent to Java `final` (when used on a class).

Comment: Scala has other access levels, too, like `private[this]`.  For this question though I focused on "What's the closest equivalent to these that I'm familiar with from C#."

Comment: @TimGoodman: Yeah, it would be somewhat equivalent to `internal sealed` in C# or `JAR final` in Java, which of course don't exist.

Comment: My god, this answer looks horrendous on a Windows phone.  (The table wraps around instead of scrolling to the right, totally breaking the column alignment.)